# Why are private keys alpha-numeric?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, asymmetric

In asymmetric encryption, if a private key is in-fact the multiplication of 2 prime numbers, then how come it is alphanumeric?

Comment: What makes you think that the keys are alphanumeric? My guess is that you are looking at an encoding (base64 or hex) of the binary key but you don't provide enough details to be sure.

Comment: I concur with @SteffenUllrich. Also, the private key is not the product of two primes. At least not for RSA. Coincidentally, that product part of the public key for RSA.

Comment: That was my guess too. But almost everywhere private keys are defined so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, keys are not alphanumeric. They are binary, but because binary is hard to work with, they are often encoded either as [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) or [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) strings.

It allows you to for example post them online, view them in a text editor and so on, while you could not do any of that properly with their binary form.

When keys are being used, they are decoded into binary again and stored in memory (RAM).

Comment: The encoding part makes sense. But, don't we chose _prime numbers_ (integers) in the beginning and work on them to create public/private keys. Then we should be able to get regular numbers. How did we end up with their binary representations?

Comment: @AdityaGupta binary numbers are regular numbers, just written differently. It is like 1000 vs one thousand. Both are the same number, just differently represented.

Comment: Yes, I get that. So are you saying that if I have a _very long_ number, it would be easier to represent it in one of the encoded formats?

Comment: @AdityaGupta I specifically said binary, because the numbers are not used in a standard way on computers, simply because computers can't normally handle numbers that large. They have to be stored and worked with in special ways, using special libraries.

Comment: @AdityaGupta base64 encoded is *shorter* than decimal representation in ASCII (64 instead of only 10 possibilities pre place) and perhaps at least as important: it is easier to convert to and from the computer-friendly internal - binary - representaion